# Better defining the [polling] and [public-opinion] tags

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

Following the discussion in [Should [public-opinion] be made a synonym of [polling], or vice-versa (or neither)?](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5857/should-public-opinion-be-made-a-synonym-of-polling-or-vice-versa-or-neithe), it seems like the [best suggestion](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5863/28994) is to redefine [polling](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/polling) to refer to the technical aspect of polling, while [public-opinion](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/public-opinion) should be used on questions asking about the results of specific polls, or polling data in general.

The best method to proceed, as far as I'm aware at least, would be as follows:

1. <strike>Produce a list of questions currently tagged with [polling](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/polling) which should remain as such</strike>
2. <strike>Moderator-merge the [polling](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/polling) tag into [public-opinion](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/public-opinion), retagging all questions with the [public-opinion](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/public-opinion) tag</strike>
3. <strike>Remove the synonym between [polling](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/polling) and [public-opinion](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/public-opinion), so that questions can once again be tagged with [polling](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/polling)</strike>
4. Go through the list of questions previously identified, manually adding the [polling](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/polling) tag.

The tag wikis also need looking at to reflect the new usage, and the current synonyms pointing to [polling](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/polling) ([opinion-polling](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/opinion-polling), [polls](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/polls), [popularity](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/popularity) and [job-approval](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/job-approval)) also need to be looked at. I suggest that the first two should remain synonymised with [polling](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/polling), while the last two should be synonyms of [public-opinion](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/public-opinion).

**Please weigh in with your thoughts!**

Below is a list of questions which I think should remain tagged with [polling](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/polling). Feel free to improve the formatting on this or edit the list if you think I've missed any (or misjudged any).

- <strike>[According to political scientists, what, if anything, are the benefits of election polling to a liberal democracy?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/62033/28994)</strike>
- [What, if anything, has been done to account for mail-in votes in 2020 exit poll data?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/60370/28994)
- [“Polling fails” observed in US elections quantified as right- or left-leaning?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/59709/28994)
- [Does trust of strangers influence how likely someone is to answer a poll from a stranger?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/59566/28994)
- [Why is the Economist model so sure Trump is going to lose compared to other models?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/59387/28994)
- [What does asterisk mean in RealClearPolitics polls?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/59298/28994)
- [Is it advantageous to lie in political polling answers?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/57939/28994)
- [How shall I understand the US election poll results conducted on Twitter, which are contradictory to the others not conducted on Twitter?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/57547/28994)
- [In the 538 Election Forecast, what is the difference between States that are: “the closest races” and “close to the tipping point”?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/56411/28994)
- [What is the name for a graph showing the estimated electoral vote share based on polling over time?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/56263/28994)
- [What differences are between polled groups “V”, “A”, “RV” and “LV”?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/54702/28994)
- [Historical data on how the reliability of polling data depends on time remaining until a US presidential election](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/54680/28994)
- [How does polling work in the United States?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/54018/28994)
- [Has anything been published about how YouGov determined the figures they are using for predicted turnout by age?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/48630/28994)
- [What is an MRP poll, and is it more accurate than a conventional poll?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/48434/28994)
- [Is current (November 2019) polling about Democrats lead over Trump trustworthy?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/47385/28994)
- [Is it possible to have a 22 point difference between polls taken over the same time period?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/47054/28994)
- [In CBC's poll tracker, why do the probabilities of winning not add up to 100%?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/46667/28994)
- [What is the purpose of polls published by the organization that they are asking about which have leading/confusing questions?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/46628/28994)
- [Why does Biden show two trend-lines with his polls?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/43692/28994)
- [Which polls count towards DNC debate requirements (especially fall)?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/43192/28994)
- [Why are there no polls of Tom Steyer yet?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/43062/28994)
- [How to poll on a budget](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/42766/28994)
- [How does Indonesia's unofficial presidential election tally finish with “head-snapping” speed?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/40710/28994)
- [How to convey poll results with shifting demographics?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/37954/28994)
- [Evidence in support of highly myopic retrospective voting](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/37469/28994)
- [How do the RealClearPolitics polling averages work?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/35750/28994)
- [Who coined the term “herding” in the context of polling?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/35445/28994)
- [What are the main differences between UK and US (NEP) exit polls, methodologically?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/32709/28994)
- [Is exit-polling more accurate than pre-election polling?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/32707/28994)
- [Why are (public) political polls typically allowed even very close to the elections despite of their apparent disruptive effect on voters perception?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/31868/28994)
- [What might “behavioral microtargeting with psychographic messaging” mean, in the context of political action committee research?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/29839/28994)
- [Is there a democratic country that bans pre-election polls for a relatively long period before the actual elections?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/26903/28994)
- [How predictive of the House Popular Vote is the Generic Ballot?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/26160/28994)
- [Does polling during election campaigns bias policy selection or affect voter turnout?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/19628/28994)
- [To what extent do election polls affect the election results?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/18359/28994)
- [Are there any methods that compensate for phenomenons such as Shy Tory factor and Bradley effect?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/16456/28994)
- [Do any jurisdictions take steps to protect people's votes from being “outed” by the polls?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/13953/28994)
- [Is there evidence that phone polling led to people's votes being “outed”?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/13952/28994)
- [Are Opinion Polls as accurate as they once were in America?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/12869/28994)
- [Have pollsters examined the possibility of a “shy Tory factor” in the 2016 presidential election?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/12839/28994)
- [Phenomenon where politically incorrect candidates do better in actual elections than in polls?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/12521/28994)
- [FiveThirtyEight: Polls Only vs Now Cast](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/11943/28994)
- [Who was polled in “The Latest Polls”?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/11818/28994)
- [How widely established are the laws against reporting on polling during election?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/11427/28994)
- [Is the “no poll reporting till voting is done” specific to Brexit vote?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/11392/28994)
- [How to extract the chance of winning from questions in the poll?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/11272/28994)
- [How is PredictWise so certain that Ted Cruz has absolutely no chance to win the 2016 Republican Party presidential primaries and caucuses?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/9969/28994)
- [Is preferred candidate polling useful in predicting the likelihood of a candidate winning the primaries?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/9132/28994)
- [Restricting polls because of the “Bandwagon effect”](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/8584/28994)
- [Do political parties pay for opinion polls?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/7943/28994)
- [Is polling about fringe beliefs reliable?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/3370/28994)
- [Did any political campaign in USA ever officially acknowledge practically using Nate Silver's model or numbers?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/920/28994)
- [Do opinion polls constitute a way of indirect demarchy?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/285/28994)
- [How can a small poll accurately model an election?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/31/28994)

Added later:

- [Are approval ratings and election results considered comparable?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/3151)
- [Where can I do my own analysis of exit poll data?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/13120)
- [Are opinion polls always representative of the extreme opinions?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/33157)

Removed from the old list:

- (not about polling or public opinion) [Does a ban on political campaigning on the day before the election affect the outcome?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/6579/28994)

Comment: I went through the whole list as well, I think we're good to go.

Comment: What should we be doing with the questions on that list? Should we edit and add [polling] to them if we think it's appropriate?

Comment: @divibisan yes, please feel free! Those in the list are those I think need the public opinion tag removed and the polling tag added, but obviously given our site’s low-ish activity we don’t want to spam up the active questions feed too much.

Plus if there’s any other issues with the questions it would be good to fix them at the same time :)

Comment: When I encountered [Why are there no polls of Tom Steyer yet?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/43062/26455), I saw "will have to have at least 2% in 4 polls" as a question about [public-opinion]; that is, "how the public views" Tom Steyer's candidacy, rather than "general and technical aspects of polling". But, then I see "they don't seem to be asking his name" which could be a [polling] question. **The final question "Is his candidacy real or not?" suggests it's not about either.** In any case, it's not about [debate] which is only mentioned. For your consideration.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I agree with the tag synonyms as you divided them. So we get:

### Main tag: [polling]

This should have the following tag synonyms: [opinion-polling](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/opinion-polling), [polls](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/polls), ...

Proposed tag description:

> Questions about general and technical aspects of polling: sampling of opinions on a subject. Questions about SPECIFIC POLLING RESULTS should use [public-opinion] instead.

*Edit*: broadened this description a bit to include 'general aspects of polling' as well.

### Main tag: [public-opinion]

This should have the following tag synonyms: [popularity](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/popularity), [job-approval](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/job-approval), ...

Proposed tag description:

> Questions asking how the public views certain issues, for example based on opinion poll results. Questions about TECHNICAL ASPECTS of opinion polling should use [polling] instead.

Comment: Upvote this comment if you think the all CAPS in the proposed tag descriptions is too much.

Comment: I'd say bold rather than caps?

Comment: @Bobson bold (or any other markup) can't be used in the tag excerpt. It's only allowed in the wiki.