# Why questions about past polls & elections?

Tags: support

Why have so many questions about past polls, mainly for the 2016 and 2020 Presidential elections, started showing up at the head of the page?  Surely they are either moot, or trivially answerable by a search of news articles?

Answer (score 8):

It's the result of a retagging effort for the [polling](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/polling) and [public-opinion](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/public-opinion) tags as discussed on meta here:

[Better defining the [polling] and [public-opinion] tags](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5879/19301)

[Should [public-opinion] be made a synonym of [polling], or vice-versa (or neither)?](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5857/19301)

Answer (score 2):

They are showing up because someone has edited the question/answer or a new answer has been posted. Most of what you are seeing are old questions that are just reappearing on the front page.

As for your second question it doesn't matter if they are moot or trivially answerable as that is not a criteria for a valid question on this site. What matters is that they are good questions that can attract good answers. What you are asking is also missing a critical point in that what is trivial for one person to find might be hard/impossible for someone else due to a lack of knowledge on what to search for.

Comment: If it's not a criterion, it should be.  As to being hard to find or not, you miss the point that (AFAIK, anyway) nobody really wants to find such questions.  Most of them really should be deleted.  (And as far as I could see, nobody edited those questions or their answers.)

Comment: @jamesqf To see why a question was bumped, you can simply click on the timestamp in the list of questions. (The list of questions also has some short descriptions - such as "modified" or "answered".) For example, after clicking on the timestamp, in [this instance I landed on the question](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/32707/is-exit-polling-more-accurate-than-pre-election-polling/?lastactivity).  There I see the text "edited 8 hours ago", after clicking on the timestamp, I get the [revision history](https://politics.stackexchange.com/posts/32707/revisions) and I see the edit.

Comment: You can also view [the timeline](https://politics.stackexchange.com/posts/32707/timeline) of that question, if you prefer this format.

Comment: @jamesqf Why should it be a criteria for closing a question? As I stated what is simple and easy for you to find might be impossible for someone else to find. If no one really wanted to find such questions why are they getting asked and answered?

Comment: @Joe W: Questions about polling &c in say the 2016 Presidential election are obviously relevant before the election.  That's when they were asked, and from those I looked at, when all the answers and comments were made.  (I could understand if someone had actually added something, but they seemed unchanged.)  Afterwards, they're irrelevant.  It's like looking at your daily weather forecast, and discovering it's actually from 2016.